# Microsoft SQL Server Database Miroring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, mirroring

I have few questions about Microsoft SQL Server database Mirroring.

1. Fail over of database is Automatic or Manual in case of Microsoft SQL database mirroring?
2. In case of failure in Primary database how new application requests will be routed to secondary database? Is it automatic or Manual? Do I need to make any change in application to connect to Secondary database or not?
3. How will I configure the application connection string in case of Microsoft SQL Database Mirroring? please share some example string.
4. Can I implement mirroring for a database that is already a snapshot replica of another Microsoft SQL database?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) yet?

Comment: Hi Muhammed!  Are you configuring *new* mirroring, or trying to understand existing mirroring? If configuring new, I'd recommend looking at Availability Groups. If you're understanding an existing configuration, that's a different story. :)

Answer (score 1):

### If you are configuring a new setup, you should *not* use Mirroring, which is [deprecated in all supported versions of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/database-mirroring-deprecation-announcement).

### All new work should use [Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) instead.

> Fail over of database is Automatic or Manual in case of Microsoft SQL database mirroring?

The answer here is "both." You'll have to read up about the Mirroring [Operating Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-operating-modes). If you're using "High Safety Mode (aka, synchronous commit), you can also use a [Witness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-witness) to have automatic failover.

> In case of failure in Primary database how new application requests will be routed to secondary database? Is it automatic or Manual? Do I need to make any change in application to connect to Secondary database or not?
> How will I configure the application connection string in case of Microsoft SQL Database Mirroring?

You can configure the connection string to use the `Failover Partner` connection string attribute. Depending on your driver, the connection string may vary, but if you are using [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/database-mirroring-in-sql-server), the connection string might look something like this:

```
 Data Source=myServerAddress;Failover Partner=myMirrorServerAddress;
```

Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;

If you use this in your connection string, your application would automatically reconnect when you fail over to secondary. Generally, if you are going to implement automatic failover with High Safety Mode & a Witness, you would need to implement a connection string like this to achieve actual automatic failover.

I have seen organizations use manual failover with network name tricks successfully--however setting the connection string is a much preferred solution.

> Can I implement mirroring for a database that is already a snapshot replica of another Microsoft SQL database?

Mirroring can be configured alongside [Snapshot Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/snapshot-replication), or other kinds of SQL Server Replication. Microsoft has some great documentation on [Replication & Mirroring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-and-replication-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). Depending on the replication topology, the specifics will vary. In general, you'll need to use a dedicated distributor and make specific configuration changes to any Snapshot, Log Reader, or Distribution agents that point at a Mirroring replica.